# SSL implementation oracle apex

Tags: ssl, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Can anyone tell me how to set up SSL / HTTPS on Oracle Apex?
I'm using Oracle Apex 5.0 and I want to be able to access my application via HTTPS.

Comment: What is your web server and what operative system are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Information on this is fairly widespread, but varies depending on your middle tier.

http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2016/05/please-use-https-for-your-apex-apps.html

https://www.skillbuilders.com/free-oracle-apex-tutorials/how-to-get-oracle-apex-ssl-web-services-working/

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6121/index-en.html

http://davidghedini.blogspot.com/2009/02/https-for-oracle-application-express-on.html

http://krisrice.io/2018-05-09-ORDS-and-lets_encrypt/

Comment: You're going to need to supply more than that to get anything from online forums.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Glassfish Server as the Middleware you will have a HTTP Listener enabled. You can enable HTTPS for that with a simple checkmark. Just go to the webinterface and have a look at the Network Settings.
Then you'll only need to get a valid SSL Certificate, for example a Free one from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

If you are using Apache Tomcat as the middleware it's similar. You gotta change the Listener to a HTTPS one and include your certificate.